# What does a "maximal $(f,g)$-chain" mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is just a quick question. I am doing a problem that constructs the proof for the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem, but I am a little confused about the terminology. The problem is stated as follows.

> Let an $(f,g)$-chain be a sequence consisting alternatively of elements of $A$ and $B$, with the element following an element $a\in A$ being $f(a)\in B$, and the element following an element $b\in B$ being $g(b)\in A$.
>
> ...
>
> b. Show that every element of $A$ and every element of $B$ is an element of a unique such maximal $(f,g)$-chain.

In this case, I'm confused by what the term maximal implies. Is it simply asking that I need to prove that for all $a \in A$ and for all $b \in B$, they can only be elements of one unique $(f,g)$ chain, where that chain is made to be as long as possible?

Also, if that's the case, then I have a quick proof, which doesn't seem rigorous enough:

Let $a \in A$ be arbitrary. Suppose $a$ is a part of two sequences. Then the term to the left is the same for both sequences, as that would be $b_1 \in B$ such that $g(b_1)=a$. But since $g$ is one-to-one, $b_1$ is unique for both sequences. The term to the right is also the same for both sequences, as that would be $f(a)$. Then, we use the same argument for all $b \in B$. This means that traversing the two chains, every element to the right of $a$ is identical and so is every element to the left of $a$ for both chains. Thus, the chains are identical.

I think the proof makes sense, but I am not sure if it is rigorous enough. Would something like induction be necessary to go through both sides of the chains?

Comment: hi, there need not be such $b_1$ if $a\not\in g(B)$. Max chains may happen to be finite, e.g. there may be $a,b$ with $b=f(a)$ and $a=g(b)$, then $\langle a,b\rangle$ is a maximal chain. Or, it seems the author does not allow that, condidering in this case the chain $\langle...,b,a,b,a,b,...\rangle$? Some chains may extend in both directions, but if $a\not\in g(B)$ then the chain $\langle a,f(a),g(f(a)),...\rangle$ extends only in the forward direction. What you write seems right, just giving you some examples to perhaps help get a better idea what the author might have meant/intended/implied